# Point to a function with less arguments

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a base function (myfunc) with more than one argument. I want to choose some arguments in the main function and then call a routine (some_routine) which will use the myfunc inside of it.

Basically I want something that makes

```
myfunc(1.,2.,x) turns to f(x)
```

Is there some way to do that?

Follows an example code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//The function
double myfunc(double tau, double chi, double phi){
double value;
//complicated process using tau, chi and x to find value.
value = tau+chi+phi;//just to work
return value;
}

//The Routine
typedef double (*function_pointer)(double);
double some_routine(function_pointer f){
// process, like finding a minimum, using some generic funcion like f(x)
double value;
double x=10;
value = f(x)*f(x);//just to work

return value;
}

//The problem
int main(){
for(double i=0.;i<10;i+=.5){
    cout << some_routine(myfunc,i,i+.1) << endl;
}
//I would like to call like that. Declaring that in "some_routine" f(x):=myfunc(1,0,x)
return 0;
}
```

I've found a similar question [in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208594/how-to-pass-a-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-a-subroutine-that-expects-a-fu), but it's another language... And a similar on [in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412964/pointer-to-a-function-with-reduced-arguments), in that question the argument to choose was just a "selector".

Comment: Sounds like some sort of currying to me?

Comment: This isn't really possible with function pointers. On the other hand, if you let `some_routine` take any callable value (by making it a template or taking `std::function<double(double)>`, it's pretty easy.

Comment: @bash.d Technically, partial application. Currying facilitates this but is strictly speaking independent.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I get you! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `std::bind`. Details here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

So

```
auto f = std::bind(myfunc, args here)
```

then use `std::function` as the datatype for the method

Comment: The same approach could alternatively be performed using a lambda: `auto f = [](X x) { return myfunc(1, 2, x); }`. Personally I'd actually use `std::bind` exactly like you suggest, but most folks here on SO seem to like lambdas better from what I've seen.